# R / data.table() merge on named subset of another data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I'm trying to put together several files and need to do a bunch of merges on column names that are created inside a loop.  I can do this fine using `data.frame()` but am having issues using similar code with a `data.table()`:

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:20, col1 =  runif(20))
df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:20, col1 =  runif(20))

newColNum <- 5
newColName <- paste('col',newColNum ,sep='')

df1[,newColName] <- runif(20)

df2 <- merge(df2, df1[,c('id',newColName)], by = 'id', all.x = T) # Works fine
######################

dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:20, col1 =  runif(20))
dt2 <- data.table(id = 1:20, col1 =  runif(20))

newColNum <- 5
newColName <- paste('col',newColNum ,sep='')

dt1[,newColName] <- runif(20)

dt2 <- merge(dt2, dt1[,c('id',newColName)], by = 'id', all.x = T) # Doesn't work
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: a few suggestions - in `data.table`, assign by reference using `:=` instead of what you did, avoid using character strings and use column names directly, and use the `data.table` join instead of `merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with `merge()`, and everything to do with how the `j` (i.e. column) index is, by default, interpreted by `[.data.table()`.

You can make the whole statement work by setting `with=FALSE`, which causes the `j` index to be interpreted as it would be in a `data.frame`:

```
dt2 <- merge(dt2, dt1[,c('id',newColName), with=FALSE], by = 'id', all.x = T)
head(dt2, 3)
#    id      col1       col5
# 1:  1 0.4954940 0.07779748
# 2:  2 0.1498613 0.12707070
# 3:  3 0.8969374 0.66894157
```

More precisely, from `?data.table`:

> with: By default 'with=TRUE' and 'j' is evaluated within the frame
>         of 'x'. The column names can be used as variables. **When
>         'with=FALSE', 'j' is a vector of names or positions to
>         select.**

Note that this could be avoided by storing the columns in a variable like so:

```
cols = c('id', newColName)
dt1[ , ..cols]
```

`..` signals to "look up one level"

Answer (score 0):

Try `dt1[,list(id,get(newColName))]` in your merge.

Comment: fyi, for many columns this is much worse than the `with=FALSE` solution, as the mere mention of "get", whips `data.table` into a frenzy and it constructs *all* the columns internally